# docker visit container from LAN

Tags: docker, networking, portforwarding

I have a program running inside a docker container and I expose the port 8888. However, when I try to connect the program from a device (in the same LAN as host machine but not the host machine) it failed. 
Here is my docker file

> FROM golang:1.10.1
>
> ......
>
> RUN go build -buildmode=plugin -o plugin.so plugin.go
>
> EXPOSE 8666:8888

And I start the container with

> docker run -it -P --network host  plugin:v0.3 bash

and run

> go  run program.go

in bash.
It says

> 2018/07/30 01:51:43 listening port 8888

But I cannot connect to the port from other device(which is in the same LAN as host machine but not the host machine)

then I tried

> docker ps -a

It looks different in that the ports column are empty(Usually there should be a mapping?)

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's working from inside the container first ?

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron It worked. Problem solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Expose won’t create port mappings for you, they’re just a “note from the designer to the user”. Add -p 8666:8888 to your Docker run command line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Tried docker run -it -p 8666:8888 --network host  plugin:v0.5 bash

No luck

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by replacing

> go run program.go

afer

> docker run -it -P --network host plugin:v0.3 bash

with

> docker run -p 8666:8888 plugin:v0.5 go run program.go

It's like magic I still don't know why but it works.(seems like docker will only do the port forwarding when the container starts)

I'll dig into it later.